# Omitting Weaviate Objects Containing Specific Reference

Tags: weaviate

Suppose I have a database of movies with some genres tagged to it. My Weaviate schema looks like this:

```json
"classes": [{
  "class": "Movie",
  "properties": [{
    "name": "name",
    "dataType": ["string"],
  }, {
    "name": "inGenres",
    "dataType": ["Genre"],
  }],
}, {
  "class": "Genre",
  "properties": [{
    "name": "name",
    "dataType": ["string"],
  }],
}]
```

I would like to exclude movies tagged with a specific genre from the search results. Specifically, for a database containing the following `Movie` objects:

```json
{"name":"foo", "inGenres":[{"name":"drama"}]}
{"name":"bar", "inGenres":[{"name":"horror"},{"name":"thriller"}]}
{"name":"baz", "inGenres":[{"name":"horror"},{"name":"sci-fi"}]}
```

If I exclude the `horror` genre, the search results should only return the movie `foo`. Is there any way to perform such a query with GraphQL or the Python client?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`where` filter](https://www.semi.technology/developers/weaviate/current/graphql-references/filters.html#where-filter) to achieve this.

In your specific case:

```
{
  Get {
    Article(
      where: {
        path: ["inGenres", "Genre", "name"],
        operator: NotEqual,
        valueString: "horror" 
      }
    ) {
      name
      inGenres {
        ... on Genre {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Python

```py
import weaviate

client = weaviate.Client("http://localhost:8080")

where_filter = {
  "path": ["inGenres", "Genre", "name"],
  "operator": "NotEqual",
  "valueString": "horror" 
}

query_result = client.query.get("Movie", ["name"]).with_where(where_filter).do()

print(query_result)
```

Comment: This returns all 3 movies, but I want `bar` and `baz` to be omitted from the results since they have a `horror` tag. It seems like the `NotEqual` operator returns objects that have references other than the target reference.